# Remote Observables in .NET

Tags: .net, dynamic, streaming, observer-pattern

I encounter this scenario all the time, but have never found anything but home-grown solutions to it:

- You view a list of orders
- When you make changes to those orders, they dynamically update on any other clients screens who are looking at the same list, and vice versa

I call this idea "Remote observables"... not sure if it has a better name.

You could argue this could be accomplished by polling, or refreshing your browser page continuously but I have seen much better ways (sockets, fancy delta tracking etc).

Zillions of frameworks let you expose your objects/data to remote clients... but I honestly cannot name any where you automatically get streamed changes to that data.

Am I missing an amazing secret framework for this? Stick writing my own?

Answer (score 1):

See [pubsubhubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/):

> Parties (servers) speaking the PubSubHubbub protocol can get near-instant notifications (via webhook callbacks) when a topic (feed URL) they're interested in is updated.

Comment: thanks i will take a look. btw I am not necessarily thinking about just web, in fact thick client is probably a more likely scenario